# Spring Batch JdbcPagingItemReader - sortKey not respected when pageSize / fetchSize are defined

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using a paging Jdbc reader in a spring batch job. I have 16 rows in a table and am expecting to see all the rows but the configuration below is only returning 10.

```
<bean id="pagingQuery" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="selectClause" value="select policy_number,val_date,name,sequence,amount,rate,frequency,start_date,end_date,basis"/>
    <property name="fromClause" value="from MyTable"/>
    <property name="sortKey" value="policy_number"/>
    <property name="whereClause" value="load_id=:jobid"/>
</bean>
<bean id="tableReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="queryProvider" ref="pagingQuery"/>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="jobid" value="1"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="fetchSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.ColumnMapRowMapper"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Without just raising the value of the paging/fetch size to above 16 is there an alternative way to configure this reader to return all rows?

Comment: have you tried not setting fetchSize; looked a few minutes over the code and might work

Comment: agh - i tried that (the fetchSize default is -1) but the issue stays the same

Comment: Just a question. Why do you a need a pageable reader if you need ALL rows in one single read? Use a standard jdbc reader with very high commit-interval (or custom CompletionPolicy)

Comment: No - i don't really need the pageable reader but i understood it was better practice it use since this results in a smaller memory footprint for a the app. I my real app i'm read at max 60,000 rows - my hack solution atm is to increase the page and fetch size to 100,000 ;-(. I'd like to better understand how the 'pageSize' and 'fetchSize' parameters interact with the SQL 'sortKey' and 'whereClause'.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue I needed to get all the data from table, Rather than jdbc I was using mybatis paging. The fact is that Since the view I was fetching was so complex. I was asked to hit(query) database once(paging requires multiple query to be executed for each page, where clause was an overhead). Hence I increased pagesize to accommodate all data, I run into memory issue( which is obvious). Since I'm not using UI to display data, paging is not really a requirement. Hence I used JDBCCursorItemReader. which queries the table once and keeps the data in database cache or temp table space( not a database expert, but because of mess up I found result set is cached in temp table space). the data is sent back to you using result set( it depends on fetch size) which you read and create object till commit interval. once the commit interval is reached, data is written. Next it again fetches the data from result set(if result set doesn't have data it will get another chunk from database as per fetch size) and creates object(row mapper) till commit interval reaches and then calls item writer. Hence I did not run out of memory. Hence you can configure commit interval based on your memory limitation. I would recommend keep fetchsize and commit-interval same to get better performance. When I tweaked fetchsize by increasing I got better execution time but not sure How It will impact else where. Here is sample JDBC cursor Item Reader

```
<bean id="cursorReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql" value="SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4,C5 FROM KP_TBL_VW" />
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="rowMapperDomain" />
        <property name="fetchSize" value="50000"/>
        <property name="driverSupportsAbsolute" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Apologize if my db understanding is wrong